# Python menuOptions modify settings

Tags: python, drop-down-menu

I would like to modify setting of a optionMenu in Python but I can modify only when you scroll down and see the options

```
actionList = ttk.OptionMenu(controller, var, *items)
    actionList['menu'].config(font = MEDIUM_FONT, bg = 'white')
    actionList.grid(column = 1 , row = 1, pady = 30)
```

when i try to use something like

```
actionList.config(bg = 'white')
```

I have an error.

The modify working but changes only if I scroll down the menu.

When I see it on the main frame have the default settings.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have to update the widget after you color it, like such;

```
actionList.config(bg = 'white')
actionList.update()
```

Comment: im sorry but ive allready write what that way isnt working
i have an error : -bg unknown option